# Number of monic polynomials of degree $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know that there are $p^2$ monic polynomials of degree $2$ over the field $\mathbb{Z}_{p}
 $ but I want to prove it precisely. Help me a hint to prove that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A degree 2 polynomial has the form $ax^2 + bx +c$.  It is monic when $a=1$.  How many choices of $b$ are there?  How many choices of $c$ are there?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ has $p$ elements there are $p$ ways to choose $b$, $p$ ways to choose $c$ so we are done. I hope I didn't have mistakes.

Comment: To be more precise, there are $p$ ways to choose $b$, and **for each** of these ways there are $p$ ways to choose $c$.

Comment: Ehm, of course.